# Multiple browser windows with separate sessions

Tags: .net, session, asp.net-mvc-4, multiple-instances

I'm starting an .NET MVC4 application that requires the use of multiple browser instances. I need each browser to have it's own instance or session per-say. For example, lets say it is an application used by a school. In the main window, a search is done for a student and selected so that everything done in that browser window is associated with the student that was selected. I open up two other browser windows and do the same thing with two different students so now each window is associated with a specific student. I don't believe I can use the Session object because it reaches across all instances of the browser. What would be the best way to implement something like this?

Comment: wouldn't you know the currently selected student based on the route?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?  If so, can you mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple possibilities here.

If each browser is viewing a student that is independent of the logged in user, then your route will give you the information for the current student, regardless of which browser instance executed the request.  Then you simply your load your student model on the fly.

For example, after the search I assume you redirect to a student page.  You can setup a url route similar to this:

http://www.blah.com/home/student/profile/123

MVC will get you to the appropriate controller with the student id = 123. Load your student and render your view.

If you wish to store the current student in the Session cache you'll have to be able to uniquely identify your student in the cache.  Instead of storing it named as "student" store it as "student-123" where 123 is the Id of the student.  Then you can write code to look for the specific student in the Session Cache. If it doesn't exist, load it on the fly.